# go debugger - Command failed: command not available

Tags: go

I'm running the golang debugger dlv and I'm trying to run go code while in the debugger. however, I keep getting an error. how do you run this from within the go debugger?

```
if 1 == 1 {
  fmt.Println("hello world")
}
Command failed: command not available
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `if 1 == 1` which I think you know is always true?

Comment: nothing really. just trying to use statements and expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate an expression in Delve now - see https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/251.  You can't execute more complex code like a statement.

Comment: is there an alternative debugger that can ? Thx.

Comment: also is there a way to make calls to other functions from dlv?
(dlv) fmt.Println("test") -> Command failed: command not available